# Unable to get URL to Contextual Image Service in Java DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

I am using DXA 1.7 Java web application from GIT hub and the DXA properties file having the below properties.

**Mapping for CID resolver (Filter or Servlet):**
`dxa.modules.cid.mapping=/cid/*`

**Class to use as a resolver for CID images:**
`dxa.modules.cid.className=com.sdl.delivery.image.filter.ContextualImageFilter`

However when I start my application I am getting the below error. Also, I do not want to use the Contextual Image service in my application. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [com.sdl.delivery.image.filter.ContextualImageFilter]
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to get URL to Contextual Image Service.
    at com.sdl.delivery.image.filter.ContextualImageFilter.getContextualImageServiceURL(ContextualImageFilter.java:197)
    at com.sdl.delivery.image.filter.ContextualImageFilter.init(ContextualImageFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4621)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the documentation you should have come accross the following topic: Enabling modules in web application (Java)

See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-4AAA4B82-6240-46F4-B248-9B503995C215

This explains that you can build your DXA sample application, and enable different modules. In your case, you should ensure that you build without the `cid-module`, so there won't be any references to it.

Comment: Thank you Bart. I removed the cid-module and rebuitd it. This resolved the issue.